# Boost keywords template

Tags: c++, templates, boost, containers, boost-multi-index

My question is about this code:

```
auto& lookup = container.template get<1>();
container.relocate(container.begin(),container.template project<0>(it));
```

1st: `.template`

From what I've found, this template keyword specified on my container is using a template, correct me if I'm wrong.

src: ([Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords))

2nd: `project<0>(it)`

Looking for the definition in the lib, I saw that it needed an iterator as a parameter, but I don't understand the `project<0>` (same for `get<1>`).

I found some information like this: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.variant, and posts on Stack Overflow too, but I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the reason why `template` can be required. Note it is only required in dependent context (where the actual specialization of a template may depend on template parameters).

The documentation is [`here`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html):

- [Indices are accessed via `get<N>()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#projection:%7E:text=Indices%20are%20accessed%20via%20get%3CN%3E())

  > where `N` ranges between 0 and the number of comparison predicates
  > minus one. The functionality of index #0 can be accessed directly from
  > a `multi_index_container` object without using `get<0>()`: for instance,
  > `es.begin()` is equivalent to `es.get<0>().begin()`.
  >
  > Note that get returns a reference to the index, and not an index
  > object. Indices cannot be constructed as separate objects from the
  > container they belong to, so the following
  >
  > ```
  > // Wrong: we forgot the & after employee_set::nth_index<1>::type
  > const employee_set::nth_index<1>::type name_index=es.get<1>();
  > ```
  >
  > does not compile, since it is trying to construct the index object
  > `name_index`. This is a common source of errors in user code.
- [Projection Of Iterators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#projection)

  > Given indices `i1` and `i2` on the same `multi_index_container`, [`project`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection) can
  > be used to retrieve an i2-iterator from an i1-iterator, both of them
  > pointing to the same element of the container. This functionality
  > allows the programmer to move between different indices of the same
  > multi_index_container when performing elaborate operations:
  >
  > ```
  > typedef employee_set::index<name>::type employee_set_by_name; employee_set_by_name& name_index=es.get<name>();
  >
  > // list employees by ID starting from Robert Brown's ID
  >
  > employee_set_by_name::iterator it1=name_index.find("Robert Brown");
  >
  > // obtain an iterator of index #0 from it1 employee_set::iterator it2=es.project<0>(it1); 
  >
  > std::copy(it2,es.end(),std::ostream_iterator<employee>(std::cout));
  > ```